# Display ListView Data in 2 columns using Xamarin Cross-Platform C# Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, grid

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to develop Cross-Platform Mobile App (iOS & Android) via Xamarin C#.

I want to display my data in ListView via 2 columns.
But, I've no idea how to do it. As far of my knowledge, I know the ListView is only display in 1 columns.

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<CardInfo> Name = new ObservableCollection<CardInfo>{
                new CardInfo{BrandName = "Brand 1"},
                new CardInfo{BrandName = "Brand 2"},
                new CardInfo{BrandName = "Brand 3"},
                new CardInfo{BrandName = "Brand 4"},
                new CardInfo{BrandName = "Brand 5"},
                new CardInfo{BrandName = "Brand 6"},
                new CardInfo{BrandName = "Brand 7"},
                new CardInfo{BrandName = "Brand 8"},
                new CardInfo{BrandName = "Brand 9"},
                new CardInfo{BrandName = "Brand 10"}

            };            

            ListViewName.ItemsSource = Name;

<ListView x:Name="ListViewName" HasUnevenRows="True" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" >

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell >
                    <Grid  >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Frame Style="{StaticResource FrameStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  >
                                <Label Text="{Binding BrandName}" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"  />
                            </Frame>

                            <Frame Style="{StaticResource FrameStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  >
                                <Label Text="{Binding BrandName}" Style= {StaticResource LabelStyle}"  />
                            </Frame>                
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: What is the `Value` in the second Frame?

Comment: What is `Value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a listview with multiple columns(i.e multiple model items in a row) you can use **[FlowListView](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView)** library.

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="2" FlowItemsSource="{Binding Name}" >

    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <Frame Style="{StaticResource FrameStyle}"  >
                   <Label Text="{Binding BrandName}" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"  />
            </Frame>

        </DataTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

</flv:FlowListView>
```

Comment: after install this flowlistview and copy your code above, debug it and the result become blank. Nothing display on the android simulator. :(

Comment: Hi sir, after I do some amendment, it is works perfectly for me. The amend I did is : 
I delete the FlowItemsSource="{Binding Name}" in XAML file, then assign name to the flowlistview, x:Name="ListViewName". 
After that, in cs file, I just add a line : ListViewName.FlowItemsSource = Name;
Then, it's works! Do you have any idea why only this way is works?

Comment: My code was just a sample code to show you just the idea and it's in [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) manner .But yours is in _code-behind_ way.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Value property inside the CardInfo class. Because that is what the line

```
<Label Text="{Binding Value}" Style= {StaticResource LabelStyle}"  />
```

is looking for. The BindingContext is the object to represent from the ItemsSource *(in your case, ItemsSource is the `Name` ObserveableCollection)* by default in a ListView item. So it is a `CardInfo` object. The `CardInfo`s in your ObserveableCollection do not have this property.

Comment: Hi sir, sorry is my mistake. the result that I want is, I want to display my card info in 2 columns. Means each row will display 2 brands side by side. But, so far, as I know the listivew is only display in 1 column by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have multiple columns, it is all controlled by the way you code design your list view item template using properties like width and minimum width. You can also use a grid within your item template that will help you take care of it.

[Here's a good example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating) from the Microsoft Xamarin's official documentation to help you.

Comment: because my listview's object data is dynamic, means it can be any number of object. data. I want using listview to display my data with 2 columns (side by side). So, if the number of object is 10, i need to add 5 rows in grid. But, what happen the number of object turn to 100?

Comment: Yeah and that's a perfect reason to use the C# example in the code shown in the link.